# Mysql request () doesn't work after AND

Tags: php, mysql, regex

when I have this request:

```
SELECT fr,text_id FROM texts 
WHERE (
    fr REGEXP '[>.:, ]le[<.:, ]' OR fr REGEXP '^le[[:space:]]?' 
    OR fr REGEXP '[[:space:]]le[[:space:]]?$'
  ) AND fr REGEXP '[>.:, ]la[<.:, ]' '' 
ORDER BY text_id DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

It works

But when I put the () it doesn't work:

```
SELECT fr,text_id FROM texts 
WHERE (
    fr REGEXP '[>.:, ]le[<.:, ]' OR fr REGEXP '^le[[:space:]]?' 
    OR fr REGEXP '[[:space:]]le[[:space:]]?$'
  ) AND (fr REGEXP '[>.:, ]la[<.:, ]') '' 
ORDER BY text_id DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

The point of putting the () is to put all the others OR together with the AND so the request shows only the result where all words typed are present in the text by searching for the ,. and other characters

So ideally this should work:

```
SELECT fr,text_id FROM texts 
WHERE (
    fr REGEXP '[>.:, ]le[<.:, ]' 
    OR fr REGEXP '^le[[:space:]]?' 
    OR fr REGEXP '[[:space:]]le[[:space:]]?$'
  ) AND (
    fr REGEXP '[>.:, ]la[<.:, ]' 
    OR fr REGEXP '^la[[:space:]]?'
  ) OR fr REGEXP '[[:space:]]la[[:space:]]?$'
  ) '' ORDER BY text_id DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

If that may helps I use this loop to get the amount of words:

```
for($i=0;$i<$wordsLenght;$i++)
    {
        if($i !== 0)
        {   

        $recherche .= " )AND (".$lang." REGEXP '[>.:, ]".$words[$i]."[<.:, ]') ";
        }
        else
        {

                if($wordsLenght == 1)
                {
                    $recherche = "".$lang." REGEXP '[>.:, ]".$words[0]."[<.:, ]' OR (".$lang."     
                    REGEXP '^".$words[0]."[[:space:]]?') OR ".$lang." REGEXP  
                    '[[:space:]]".$words[0]."[[:space:]]?$'";                   
                }
                else
                {
                    $recherche = "(".$lang." REGEXP '[>.:, ]".$words[0]."[<.:, ]' OR ".$lang."    
                    REGEXP '^".$words[0]."[[:space:]]?' OR ".$lang." REGEXP 
                    '[[:space:]]".$words[0]."[[:space:]]?$'";
                }

        }
    }
```

It's in a function that is used as an argument in another fuction that part of it corresponds to the mysql request after WHERE.

Comment: What are you hoping to do with those empty `''`'s?

Comment: try SELECT fr,text_id FROM texts WHERE (fr REGEXP '[>.:, ]le[<.:, ]' OR fr REGEXP '^le[[:space:]]?' OR fr REGEXP '[[:space:]]le[[:space:]]?$' )AND (fr REGEXP '[>.:, ]la[<.:, ]') '' ORDER BY text_id DESC LIMIT 0, 20

Comment: the '' came from previous coding and I didn't want to remove it in case it has an impact on the rest of the app, big projects makes me rather cautious, I check all this stuff and once everything works I remove it, nicer peace of mind ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to remove these seemingly superfluous '' after the last ) ?

```
SELECT fr,text_id FROM texts 
WHERE (
    fr REGEXP '[>.:, ]le[<.:, ]' OR fr REGEXP '^le[[:space:]]?' 
    OR fr REGEXP '[[:space:]]le[[:space:]]?$'
  ) AND (fr REGEXP '[>.:, ]la[<.:, ]')
ORDER BY text_id DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

Comment: that was the base for the rest to work! You saved me a lot of time  and less stress, thank you soo much!

Comment: no problem, it looks like a nightmare of a query to maintain

Comment: I'll take that as a compliment ^^ So far I'm eager to progress quickly and thanks to you it keeps me inspired!